# Laravel service provider is not executed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have basically called: `php artisan make:provider RiakServiceProvider` but the new provider does not seem to be called. I have added a var_dump in both `boot` and `register` methods.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RiakServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot() {
        var_dump('Should be call second');die;
    }

    public function register() {
        var_dump('Should be call first');die;
    }
}
```

But this does not seem to be called. Neither through the web server, neither in PHPUnit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also [register your service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#registering-providers) in the `providers` field of `config/app.php`. Also, run `composer dumpauto` command.

Comment: @JilsonThomas, `dumpauto` also works, it's a synonym to `dump-autoload`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin: Good to know that :)

Comment: I edited your answer to make it less relying on external information.